# How can different groups of measurements be stored in a database table?

Tags: database, database-design

This is a puzzle about storing a big mess of data in a database.

Suppose I have a facility full of machines, each measuring time series of multiple quantities. I'll try to explain with a toy example.

`MachineA` measures four temperatures and a humidity. `MachineB` measures one temperature and five voltages. `MachineC` measures wind speed and direction. The measurements are happening all the time, automatically.

Each machine makes all of its own measurements at the same time, but the time interval and offset varies among machines. That means a row can only contain measurements from one machine taken at one timestamp.

In reality there are two thousand machines. That means using a separate table for every machine or type of machine is impractical.

Different machines are being added all the time. A set of columns that spans all possible measurements is not practical because if I add a `MachineD` with a saltiness measurement, I will not have thought about saltiness ahead of time and I'd have to add a new column to a really big table just for that one machine to use.

Typical queries:

- What was `MachineA`'s maximum temperature in the last 90 days?
- What were all of `MachineB`'s measurements for the last 7 days?
- Among all machines having temperature measurements, what was the minimum temperature measured yesterday?
- For each machine having a temperature measurement, what was the minimum temperature measured yesterday?
- Which machines having saltiness detectors also have measurements within the last year?
- What is the wind chill based on `MachineC`'s wind speed and `MachineB`'s temperature?

How can this be organized within these constraints?

Comment: If everything is being measured as a numeric value, just store that value and then store which *unit of measurement* in a separate column.  That column can be an ENUM or a string, with a foreign constraint on a *valid measurements* table.

Comment: @MikeChristensen, it's not enough to just store the unit; the name of the quantity must also be stored ("widget 4 temp"). Your suggestion can accommodate this, but when I get a million rows from this database, most of the transfer will be spent on labels and not measurements, right? Is there a way around this?

Comment: You probably need to think about what types of queries you need to support.  If it's just a giant log of data, you can probably just serialize everything as strings or reconsider using a relational DB in the first place.  If you need to query for certain types of measurements or certain machines or certain widgets, you'll need to normalize your data in a way that supports that.

Comment: Does "four temperatures and a humidity" *mean* the same thing for all the machines that measure four temperatures and a humidity? Or if not for *all* such machines, at least for a group of such machines?

Comment: @MikeChristensen, I'll update the question.

Comment: @Catcall, yes for a group of such machines. It is rare for the group to have more than one member.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few *dimensions* in this data

- Machine (location?): the thing that produced the measurement
- "analyte" : the thing that is being measured
- (obviously) time: the time of measurement.

These three items, in some form, *must be* part of the Primary Key.
The only functional dependant attribute would be *measurement": the actual outcome of the measurement process. Its unit is not important (since it is also functionally dependent on the three keyfields; though there *may* be an extra pseudo dimention "aparatus type", or it may even depend on the location. Or even time. Sigh... ).

In real-world problems like these, there always is a hidden dependancy: location X **only** makes measuments of {temperature, windspeed, humidity}, and **always** with measuring device Y.

That's where BCNF enters the picture. Not knowing your data, I cannot tell. If I *did* know your data, I could not tell either: the dependancies between the 3..4 key elements could change over time.